# iphone app pop3 server api?

Tags: ios, xcode, api, pop3

I'm developing an iphone app  that is supposed to read and send mails.
For sending mail I've used

```
MFMailComposeViewController
```

class and for IMAP server I've used MailCore API.
Now the main problem is connecting with POP3 server. I'm looking for APIs
that would allow me to communicate with POP3 server. I googled a lot but
found nothing except [Chilkat Soft](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp) which has a trial version of 30 days. Any suggestion is welcomed. I'm using Xcode.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any useful API's and solved the issue with PHP, by maintaining server :(